# I build apk with React-Native, but it doesn´t work on my tablet

Tags: android, react-native, apk, tablet

I'm new in React Native. I build an apk, that works on my phone, but it doesn't work on my tablet and I don´t know why it doesn´t work.

My tablet says "Analysis error: A problem occurred while parsing the package"

It's a Galaxy Tab E - Android: 4.4.4

I need help with this, please.

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Solo Carnes Vinos",
    "slug": "solocarnesvinos",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "android":{
      "package":"com.agenciafina.solocarnesvinos",
      "versionCode":2,
      "permissions":[]
    },
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some info about your `Android/build.gradle` file?

The line with `minSdkVersion` needs to be `minSdkVersion = 19` to work on the version of your tablet.

[Heres's](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) a list with the respective numbers of each SDK version of the Android itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t have the 'Android/build.gradle', but I've a file called build.gradle with nothing, only with this line:

```
//Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```